# Can't ping server via VPN when WAN interface is enabled

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, cockpit

I am not 100% sure if this is the correct exchange to be putting in my networking issues, but the trigger is a Linux system so I feel as though I will have more success here.

I am trying to set up a web server that will host a small API that I have written. This VM is running AlmaLinux and has two interfaces:

- **enp1s0** - public IP
- **enp6s0** - private network

The first things I did when I got the AlmaLinux box was enable the web GUI, allow interfaces to be managed by NetworkManager, join the private network and then disable the public interface so that the API is not accessible while I am hooking it all up. To get access to the private network, I VPN into an OPNSense box.

I set my API up in docker (podman) and it all works internally, so I decided to enable the public facing interface, *enp1s0*, so that I can see the magic happening in the real world. The good news is that the API is working, so congrats to me for following a tutorial to a T. The bad news is that my PC is no longer able to ping the AlmaLinux box (*Request timed out.*) and the web GUI is not accessible while VPNed in, however all the machines that I have in the private network can ping each other and when I RDP into one of my Windows servers, I can access the web GUI.

I thought that the OPNSense box might have been blocking traffic, but it picks up the icmp and allows it through. Routing is not my strong suit, so it probably has something to do with that. All help is appreciated. I don't even know where to look.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Updated language to simplify question

Comment: Try to trim down the question to the actual problem. With actual commands and actual output. In networking, it is sometimes a good idea to go for the basic stuff first, say, get a ping across. If that is not working, then just state that (with all the information about the system you are using). In your case a "cannot ping over the vpn when wan is up" might receive more attention. Lots of people will know how to help you with that, whereas not many might know what Cockpit is (I don't) and it doesn't really seem to be part of the problem.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Fair point. I know so little that I assume that everything I know is public knowledge. But with Linux being so massive, that is a very unfair assumption. Thanks :) Updated.